# Problems locating license for Deployer microservice

Tags: deployer, microservices

I have configured the SDL Web 8 Deployer as a standalone microservice. When I try to start the service, I get this error in the logs:

> 2016-04-06 10:36:37,873 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deployerController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: License file 'cd_licenses.xml' could not be found.

In the cd_storage_conf.xml file of the service, I have the following:

```
<License Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\config\cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

I have also tried these variants:

```
<License Location="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SDL Web\\config\\cd_licenses.xml"/>
<License Location="C:/Program Files (x86)/SDL Web/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

In the configuration of my Content service, I have the following, and it works:

```
<License Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\config\cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

If I copy the license file into the config folder of the Deployer service, it works correctly, but I'd rather keep my license file in a single location.

Why does the Deployer appear to work differently to the other (apparently similar) services, and how can I get it to accept the license location? Is there something else that needs to be configured in addition to the storage conf? (I tried adding a License element at the bottom of the cd_deployer_conf.xml, but I got a schema validation error.)

Comment: Have you configured the license file in the "cd_deployer_conf.xml" also? because the deployerController must be using cd_deployer_config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your other configuration files. You probably also need a License location configured in your [cd_deployer_conf.xml](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-29A0EB91-A317-4CAC-B641-D0BCBAB9BB7A)

Comment: This was indeed the problem. My mistake had been to interpret the schema validation message as meaning that I shouldn't have a License element in the deployer config. In fact, it is allowed but not at the bottom of the Deployer element, which is where I'd placed it.

Comment: didn't you see my comment before this answer?

Comment: Thanks Raul. Unfortunately I can't accept answers from both of you. I hope everyone votes up your comments though.

Comment: There's no conspiracy... Stack Exchange was not the only place this question was discussed ;) http://i.imgur.com/mlRHjMp.jpg